# Maximo REST API WHERE clause

Tags: where-clause, maximo

I am calling this MAXIMO REST API to fetch incidents belonging to a group:

```
https://doamin/maximo/oslc/os/mxosincident?lean=1&oslc.pageSize=10&oslc.select=*&oslc.where=ownergroup="I-AMS-TEST-VG"
```

The above query works fine, I get all incidents belonging to I-AMS-TEST-VG for 0-9 pages.

I want to further filter it based on Incident status - INPROG, QUEUED, SLAHOLD

So I added this additional clause to the WHERE clause:

```
https://domain/maximo/oslc/os/mxosincident?lean=1&oslc.pageSize=10&oslc.select=*&oslc.where=ownergroup="I-AMS-TEST-VG"&status IN ["INPROG","SLAHOLD","QUEUED"]
```

But the above query is fetching all incident status. As per the Maximo documentation, I see the above syntax is OK.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That ampersand (&) in your where clause actually splits the parameter up. I think if you just change it to the word "and", like you would do in a typical where clause inside of Maximo, it will work. (Though I can't remember if those brackets need to be parenthesis instead too.)

```
&oslc.where=ownergroup="I-AMS-TEST-VG" and status IN ["INPROG","SLAHOLD","QUEUED"]
```